# Associating .csv column data for calculations

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am a complete nube to Python3 and coding so go easy on me please. :)

As a project I'm creating a football league table based on 2018 EPL results. I have been able to break the .csv file containing an entire seasons worth of data into round by round results, into .csv using Pandas module. Now I need to extract the table points for each team by round, based on the home and away goals for each team. I'm having a hard time associating the goals with the teams in each fixture. I can figure out how to apply win/draw/lose (3/1/0) points but only mandrolically per fixture, not dynamically for all fixtures in the round. Then I need to write the table to another .csv file.

FTHG-Full Time Home Goals, FTAG-Full Time Away Goals, FTR-Full Time Result

- Example Data

Unnamed: 0,Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR

0,10/08/2018,Man United,Leicester,2,1,H

1,11/08/2018,Bournemouth,Cardiff,2,0,H

2,11/08/2018,Fulham,Crystal Palace,0,2,A

3,11/08/2018,Huddersfield,Chelsea,0,3,A

4,11/08/2018,Newcastle,Tottenham,1,2,A

5,11/08/2018,Watford,Brighton,2,0,H

6,11/08/2018,Wolves,Everton,2,2,D

7,12/08/2018,Arsenal,Man City,0,2,A

8,12/08/2018,Liverpool,West Ham,4,0,H

9,12/08/2018,Southampton,Burnley,0,0,D

- Example Code

  ```
  import pandas as pd

  results = pd.read_csv("2018 Round 1.csv")

  team = results.iloc[2,2]

  if results.iloc[2,4] > results.iloc[2,5]:

      points = 3

  elif results.iloc[2, 4] < results.iloc[2, 5]:

      points = 0

  else:
      results.iloc[2, 4] = results.iloc[2, 5]

      points = 1


  table_entry = (team + " " + str(points))

  print(table_entry)

  table_entry = pd.to_csv("EPL Table Round 1.csv", index = False)
  ```

  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps :) 
Please fell free to ask if the code it's not clear

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('foot.txt')

#Make a list with all tema names
Home_teams = pd.unique(df['HomeTeam'])
Away_teams = pd.unique(df['AwayTeam'])
teams = np.concatenate((Home_teams, Away_teams))

df_teams =  pd.DataFrame(columns=['team', 'points'])

#For each team in the list...
for team in teams:
    print("*******" + team+ "*****")
    points = 0
    df_home = df[(df['HomeTeam'] == team)]
    res_home = df_home['FTR'].value_counts()
    try:
        points += res_home['H']*3;
    except:
        print("Didn't win when Home")
    try:
        points += res_home['D']*1;
    except:
        print("No Draws")

    df_away = df[(df['AwayTeam'] == team)]
    res_away = df_away['FTR'].value_counts()
    try:
        points += res_away['A']*3;
    except:
        print("Didn't win when Away")

    df_teams = df_teams.append({'team': team, 'points': points}, ignore_index=True)

    print(team +"has "+ str(points) +" points" )
```

Comment: G'day @Ivan, I had a rethink about how I could go about this after asking my question and came up with something based around the FTR field similar to this but couldn't make it work.columns = pd.("Serial", "HomeTeam", "AwayTeam", "FTHG", "FTAG", "FTR")
match_result = ()
if columns("FTR" == "H"):
    home_win = columns("HomeTeam")
    home_win = 3
elif columns("FTR" == "A"):
    away_win = columns("AwayTeam")
    away_win = 3
elif columns("FTR" == "D"):
    draw = columns()
    draw = 1
else:
    loss = 0

print("HomeTeam", match_result)

Comment: I see, we had a similar idea, I recommend you to check how I looped over the tems with `for team in teams:` . Also , for conditions you may fin useful this notation: `df[(df['HomeTeam'] == team)]`

Comment: Also, for sharing coda like that you could do an *edit* on the question

Comment: I just added `df_teams ` to make a better visualization